# Error to get All services and cheracteristcs from ble device using Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

Hi I am trying to connect a bluetooth device using the Polidea/react-native-ble-plx library.

First I do the scan and it works fine:

```
scanAndConnect() {
console.log('scanAndConnect');
this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
//console.log('Scanning...' + error);
if (error) {
// Handle error (scanning will be stopped automatically)
console.log('Scanning ERROR');
return;
}
if ((device.id=== '54:6C:0E:A0:7B:6D') 
{
console.log('device found: ' + device.name + '(' + device.id + ')');
this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
}
}
```

The second step I try to connect. And it s works too!

```
device.connect().then((dev) => {
          console.log("try to connect")          
        }).then((dev) => {
          console.log("success to connect")
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("connect error:" + error)
          throw error
        });
```

So, now I want to get all the services and charactrists to read some informations from device, but this feature doesnt work for me.

I am using this method
device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();

And I always received an error.

Some time I receive the follow error message: 
1)  WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
    BleError: Device 54:6C:0E:A0:7B:6D is not connected

I didnt understand the first one, because I have the device connected.

```
var status = this.manager.isDeviceConnected(device.id).then((status)=>console.log('status1: '+status))
```

the line above returns false before I call the connect method and it returns true after it.

But when I try to get the services and characteristics I have the message that the device isnt connected